# Add an Edit Button/Icon at end of columns of Blazorise.DataGrid View BLAZOR

Tags: c#, datagridview, blazor, datagridviewcolumn, blazorise

currently I'm trying to get an edit button in every column smth like that:

[image: Picture with edit button]

My code currently looks like:

```
<DataGrid Data="@ViewModel.SurveyInstances"
          TItem="SurveyInstance"
          Bordered="true"
          ShowPager="false"
          Sortable="true">
    <DataGridColumns>
        <DataGridColumn TItem="SurveyInstance" Field="Partner.Name" Caption="Partner Name" Width="10%"/>
        <DataGridColumn TItem="SurveyInstance" Field="Survey.Title_DE" Caption="Survey Title" Width="10%"/>
        <DataGridColumn TItem="SurveyInstance" Field="@nameof(SurveyInstance.Date)" Caption="Date" Width="10%"/>
    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

Out of this I get the following:

[image: DataGrid Table]

I would love to get an edit button after the DateTime for every column :)

Comment: Where `DataGrid` comes from? It's not a Blazor out of the box component.

Comment: My question is relevant. If you don't want to explain where the control comes from, please explain if your `DataGridColumn` allows controls inside, like  `<DataGridColumn><YourButton /></DataGridColumn>`

Comment: I think you mean "for every row", not "every column". And do tell us which DataGrid this is. Questions should contain all relevant information.

Comment: @daniherrera yeah it's possible to place cntrols inside the ```<DataGridColumn>``` @HenkHolterman And the DataGrid is from Blazorise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281786/multiple-functions-to-be-render-in-clicked-editcommandtemplate-datagrid-blazoris kindly help with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How for [Blazorise.DataGrid](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid) extension add command columns
to add, edit, delete, save, cancel, etc.? The answer to the question is as follows:

1. Firstly, so that you can somehow edit the datagrid, for the
   `<DataGrid/>` you need to set the parameter `Editable = "true"`. How to install `<DataGrid/>`? [here](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/#datagrid).
2. The same must be done in the columns (`<DataGridColumn/>`) in which you
   need to edit, set the parameter `Editable = "true"`. Then inside you need to add a `<EditTemplate />` template to handle editing the values. More details [here](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/#edittemplate).
3. Secondly, you need to add the `<DataGridCommandColumn/>` command
   column inside the `<DataGrid>` component (after the DateTime
   column).
4. And then finally add an edit button (`<EditCommandTemplate/>`)
   inside the `<DataGridCommandColumn/>` component. You can familiarize yourself with other commands here: [subsection Command Templates](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/#command-templates)

And how it will actually look like, an example is shown for only one column (Name):

```xml
    <DataGrid Data="@SurveyInstances"
          TItem="SurveyInstance"
          Bordered="true"
          ShowPager="false"
          Sortable="true"
          Editable="true">
    <DataGridColumns>

        <DataGridColumn TItem="SurveyInstance" 
                        Field="Name" 
                        Caption="Partner Name" 
                        Editable="true">

            <DisplayTemplate>
                @context.Name
            </DisplayTemplate>

            <EditTemplate>
                <TextEdit TValue="string"
                          Text="@((string)context.CellValue)"
                          TextChanged="@( v => {
                                                    context.CellValue = v;
                                                    context.UpdateCell( nameof( SurveyInstance.Name ), v);
                                              })" />
            </EditTemplate>

        </DataGridColumn>

        <DataGridColumn TItem="SurveyInstance" 
                        Field="Title" 
                        Caption="Survey Title"
                        Editable="false"/>

        <DataGridCommandColumn TItem="SurveyInstance">

            <EditCommandTemplate>
                <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@context.Clicked">Edit</Button>
            </EditCommandTemplate>

        </DataGridCommandColumn>

    </DataGridColumns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: What a great answer thanks a lot!