# Multiple functions to be render in Clicked EditCommandTemplate DataGrid Blazorise

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazorise

[on edit the bit should be true and also context.clicked should also work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVr7W.png)

[this is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBXb.png)

Clicked="@(()=> OnEditBtn(context))"

Comment: Please don´t post images of code or error messages. Code in images cannot be copied and tested. [edit] your question and add the code as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not quite sure what is your problem, you could try to expand on your question.

Secondly if your problem is not showing some component after changing variable, try to call `StateHasChanged()` to redraw component, if your `OnEditBtn` function is the bound function in <Button Clicked=@..., could be the issue.

But I am just guessing with what I have to work with.